# Cannot create container for service : invalid volume specification: '/e/samples/dockerwebapp/dockerwebapp:C:\inetpub\wwwroot:rw'

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose, docker-for-windows, docker

I created a new web api project and selected "Enable Docker support". My project get created and build successfully. But when i run the project with "docker" as launcher then the i get the below error.

```
The DOCKER_REGISTRY variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Cannot create container for service dockerwebapp: invalid volume specification: '/e/samples/dockerwebapp/dockerwebapp:C:\inetpub\wwwroot:rw'
```

I created a file with name ".env" with the content

```
"COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1"
```

and placed in the same folder of docker-compose.yml, still it does not run. I get the same error.

I did not change anything in the project. My Vs2017 version

[image]

My Docker version

[image]

docker-compose.override.yml

```
version: '3.4'

    services:
      dockerwebapp:
        ports:
          - "80"
    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: nat
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerwebapp:
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Dockerfile

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  dockerwebapp:
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

Comment: In your volume spec path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot' is host path or target path? Syntax is `-v <source_path_from_docker_host>:<target_path_in_container>`. Sharing your docker-compose.yml, Dockerfile and how you run the container would help to get a quick answer.

Comment: have updated the docker files  content

Comment: Thanks, what is the image you want to use for your services->dockerwebapp? Add that to docker-compose.yml. You may take off other 2 files from your question as they are not needed.

Comment: yes dockerwebapp

Comment: Based on current docker-compose.yml, dockerwebapp is the name of the service not the image name. Image is something you need to add as `image: <imagename>`. Please read it here - https://docs.docker.com/compose/